# Reflection of class type

Tags: c#, reflection, quartz-scheduler

I want to some how pass in the class type as a parameter into a method. Something like this

```
public void DoWork<TClass>(int time)
{
     IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TClass>()
                .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                .Build();
}
```

is it possible to get the classtype as a parameter or somehow get the class type by reflection of an object of that type?

UPDATE 1:
I just tried to use a generic type and received this error

```
`The type TClass cannot be used as type parameter T in the generic type or method quartz.jobbuilder.create<T>().  There is now boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from tclass to quartz.ijob`
```

Create MEthod of Quartz

```
// Summary:
    //     Create a JobBuilder with which to define a Quartz.IJobDetail, and set the
    //     class name of the job to be executed.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     a new JobBuilder
    public static JobBuilder Create<T>() where T : IJob;
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Create` method ?

Comment: I put it in my original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for a [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) function -- this allows your function to specify a type parameter:

```
public void DoWork<TClass>(int time)
    where TClass : quartz.ijob
{
    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TClass>()
        .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
        .Build();
}
```

**Edit**

You can also place a restriction on the type parameter, which seems to be what is required here.  Use the syntax `where TClass : quartz.ijob`.

**Edit #2**

Note that callers of a generic method must specify the type parameter.  So, you'd have to call:

```
DoWork<SomeClassType>(123);
```

However, if the signature of the method includes a parameter of the generic type, then the compiler can use that to infer the type.  So, if the signature is:

```
public void DoWork<TClass>(int time, TClass instance)
    where TClass : quartz.ijob
```

Then a caller could invoke it like this:

```
var myInstance = new SomeClassType();  // SomeClassType must inherit quartz.ijob
DoWork(123, myInstance);
```

Above, the type of `myInstance` is *known at compile time*, so the compiler can infer the generic type.  However, if your type instance is [boxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx), then the type isn't known until runtime, and the compiler can't help you:

```
function SomethingOrOther(object instance)
{
    DoWork(123, instance);   // will not compile, as the compiler doesn't know the type of "instance"
}
```

In this scenario, it *is* possible to call `DoWork` anyway, by using reflection (see [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).  However, this approach of using reflection on generics gets complicated, fast.  It also defeats the purpose of generics (ie, compile-time safety), and usually indicates a design flaw.

Comment: this seem to fix the error, i havent tested it just yet I will report back after I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, yes.

You can get type of class with `typeof(YourClassHere)` or type of object with `yourObject.GetType()`.

Then you can easily create object with an acitvator: `Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters for constructor)`

**EDIT AFTER QUESTION EDIT**
It's even easier when you have the generic.

```
public void DoWork<TClass>(int time)
{
     IJobDetail job = (IJobDetail) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TClass), null /* no parameters */);
                job.WithIdentity("job1", "group1");
                job.Build();
}
```